# Hover state for label with nested span and input

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm trying to run a hover state for a specific label (not all) that forms a custom radio button by nesting an input field and a span element, like so -

```
<label>
    <input id="sample" name="sample" type="radio" value="sample">
    <span></span>
    Sample
</label>
```

The hover state should be that of a cursor pointer change. How would I go about to achieve this? Right now only the span (which is a custom radio button design) gets a pointer cursor. If the user hovers the label text nothing happens.

Comment: How about `label {
  cursor:pointer;
}`?

Comment: Like I said I only want to have this event on labels that are tied to radio buttons or checkboxes, not for say text input labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not wrap the text in `em`, `i`, etc tags and style with `cursor: pointer`?

```css
label em {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-style: normal;
  }
```

```html
<label>
    <input id="sample" name="sample" type="radio" value="sample">
    <span></span>
    <em>Sample</em>
</label>
```

EDIT - further to comments below, please see the following:

```css
label, label *:not(input) {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-style: normal;
  }
```

```html
<label>
    <input id="sample" name="sample" type="radio" value="sample">
    <span></span>
    Sample
</label>
```

Since you can't select actual text nodes with CSS (i.e. - "Sample" in your example), we can use CSS to style the `label` as a whole and its descendants, but with the exception of the input (`:not(input)`)

Comment: Thanks but I rather find a solution where I don't have to add additional markup (unless its impossible).

Comment: @StaffanEstberg I've thought of another way, please see revised edit.

Comment: @StaffanEstberg no worries, glad to help!